# How can I loop dates for a specified time?

Tags: php

I need to loop dates, according to different `$eventname`. I was already able to write a script that adds one week to the original date, but I don't know how I can loop it for a defined time.

code used:

```
    $eventname = $event->title;

    // TODO: loop for specified times if $eventname contains definded strings

    $start_date = helper('com://site/ohanah.date.format', array(
        'date' => $event->start,
        'format' => 'Y/m/d H:i',
        'timezone' => 'UTC'
    ));
    $date = strtotime($start_date) + 604800;
    echo "<pre>";
    echo date('d. F Y, H:i', $date);
    echo ' - ';
    echo helper('com://site/ohanah.date.format', array(
        'date' => $event->end,
        'format' => 'H:i',
        'timezone' => 'UTC'
    ));
    echo "</pre>";
```

Output: (start date would be one week before) `18. April 2018, 14:00 - 16:00`

So my question is, how can I loop this that the output is e.g. 6 times with one week space between each of them?

Comment: please clarify the expected result; you want to print some dates between the events start and end maybe ?

Comment: @zedling yes, I want to print this 6 times, with the output of my question, but always with one week added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When working with dates and times, do not add seconds to timestamps or something like that, because it will get you in trouble in leapyears and daylight saving times, because one day is not always 86400 seconds.

Better use PHP's DateTime and DateInterval classes.

```
<?php
$Date = new DateTime("2018-03-03 14:00:00");

for($i=0;$i<6;$i++) { //loop 6 times
    $Date->add(new DateInterval('P1W')); //add one week
    echo $Date->format("Y-m-d H:i:s").PHP_EOL;

}
```

Output:

```
2018-03-10 14:00:00
2018-03-17 14:00:00
2018-03-24 14:00:00
2018-03-31 14:00:00
2018-04-07 14:00:00
```

See also:
http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php
http://php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php

Comment: this looks great but how can I define the times it should get looped?

Comment: replace the do/while construct with a for($i=0;$i<6;$i++). i have updated my answer.

Comment: Okay, this works but is it somehow possible to add the `-` and the second `helper`? Because if I do it with extra `echo`s, it will create a new line :/

Comment: the PHP_EOL will add a newline. If you remove it, echo creates no newlines.

Comment: Great to know, now it works :) Is it somehow possible to change the Language of the Months it generates? Because currently it is English but I need German.

Comment: Yes, I already saw that post, but I just rewrote your answer with strftime, so it always uses German :) But thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Something like that?

```
<?php
$oneWeek = 604800;
$date = '2018-04-05';
$dates = array($date);

for ($i = 0; $i < 6; $i++) {
    $dates[] = $date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date) + $oneWeek);
}

var_dump($dates);
```

Comment: I tried your answer, but I get this as an output:  `array(7) { [0]=> string(16) "2018/04/08 17:00" [1]=> string(14) "15. April 2018" [2]=> string(14) "22. April 2018" [3]=> string(14) "29. April 2018" [4]=> string(12) "06. May 2018" [5]=> string(12) "13. May 2018" [6]=> string(12) "20. May 2018" }`

Comment: Hello, I think I did put it in a way to inspire you, seeing the output looks like you did some change to the code, but looks correct, what do you need?

Comment: Nothing changed, just used the `helper` on the `$date` as this loads dynamically the dates from the events. I just want the dates without anything else.

Comment: What's wrong on the output what do you want to change exactly in this output?

Answer (score 0):

I am not entirely sure I understand the question, but it looks like you want to have a condition that will either set a specific number of times for the output loop or determine whether the loop is ran that number of times.

If so, you can set a counter variable with your condition, then run the loop that number of times, defaulting the counter variable to 1 in the case that you do not want to output more than one time:

```
$eventname = $event->title;

// TODO: loop for specified times if $eventname contains definded strings
$counter = (/*your condition for $eventname*/) ? 6 : 1;
for ($x = 0; $x < $counter; $x++) {
    $start_date = helper('com://site/ohanah.date.format', array(
        'date' => $event->start,
        'format' => 'Y/m/d H:i',
        'timezone' => 'UTC'
    ));
    $date = strtotime($start_date) + 604800;
    echo "<pre>";
    echo date('d. F Y, H:i', $date);
    echo ' - ';
    echo helper('com://site/ohanah.date.format', array(
        'date' => $event->end,
        'format' => 'H:i',
        'timezone' => 'UTC'
    ));
    echo "</pre>";
}
```

Comment: @zedling, wrong place to comment.  I am not sure what the expected results are either, and I think you meant to put this comment on the question, not the answer..

Comment: I don't know if I understood the `$counter` correctly but I put a `6` in it and it just displays the date 6 times but it doesn't add one week each to the new output.

Comment: @YoKoGFX - I think I understand your question better now, and if I am correct, @ankabout has the right idea.  Their `$dates` array should be populated with 6 dates, one week apart.  Then you just need to output them with a `foreach($dates as $date)` loop